# how to Use BMP image file for background of winform in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have winform and i use image.BMP for background of my form and when i run it This happened :

[image]

It is working but my problem is background of datagridview
I don't want to see the behind the datagridview
How can i run that form with showing datagridview normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use loop and change color of each cell. Do it after set datasource.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.Rows) 
    {
         row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White; 
    }
```